# How to show file uploaded successfully alert message in JQuery File 'uploadify' plugin?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, uploadify

I'm using Jquery File Uploadify plugin for Document upload which has **multiple** true, When i use alert in OnComplete function is showing multiple alerts when uploading the documents..

```
function loadSwf(){    
    $("#fileuploader").fileUpload({
            'uploader':  "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/FileUpload/uploader.swf")",
            'cancelImg':  "@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/clearBtn.png")",
            'buttonText': 'Browse Files',
            //'buttonImg' : "@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/attachDoc.png")",
            'script': "@Url.Content("~/Documents/Upload/")",   
            'folder': "@Url.Content("~/Documents/")",
            //'fileDesc': 'Documents Files',
            'fileExt': '*.pdf;*.doc;*.ppt;*.xls',
            'multi': true,
            'auto': false,                 
            'scriptData': {'ActivityID': $('[id="ActivityID"]').val(), 'Description' :  "test" },
            'onComplete': function(settings, data) {  
             alert("File Uploaded Successfully");
        }
        });
}
```

This code is working fine for uploading one file. 
But when i upload multiple files I am getting that alert message for each file !!
How to get that alert message only once after uploading all files, instead of one alert per file.

Comment: place here some code or in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **[onQueueComplete](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/onqueuecomplete/)** event

```
$("#fileuploader").fileUpload({
    'uploader':  "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/FileUpload/uploader.swf")",
    'cancelImg':  "@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/clearBtn.png")",
    'buttonText': 'Browse Files',
    //'buttonImg' : "@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/attachDoc.png")",
    'script': "@Url.Content("~/Documents/Upload/")",   
    'folder': "@Url.Content("~/Documents/")",
    //'fileDesc': 'Documents Files',
    'fileExt': '*.pdf;*.doc;*.ppt;*.xls',
    'multi': true,
    'auto': false,                 
    'scriptData': {'ActivityID': $('[id="ActivityID"]').val(), 'Description' :  "test" },
        'onQueueComplete' : function(queueData) {
            alert("Files Uploaded Successfully");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please check the documentation